# Processing: Calling Capture class within a class possible?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to learn how to create classes in Processing, but I can't get the Capture class to work with the same code I would use in the main file of the program.

```
import processing.video.*;

class Game{

    Capture video;

    void videoFunction()
    {

      video = new Capture(this, width, height, 30);
      video.start();

     }

}
```

The error I'm getting is that `the constructor Capture(filename.Game, int, int, int) is undefined`

I'm guessing the problem is either with using `this` or with using the `width` and `height` variables. I can see that in the error message `this` is printed as the filename of the class, and not the filename of the main PDE.

How do I get the class to recognise `this` as the main filename, or `width`, and `height` as the width and height of the main program?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Game class inside the Processing sketch, or is it in its own tab?

If it's inside the main sketch tab, then you can use the name of the sketch to specify what you mean by "this". Something like this:

```
void setup(){
  Test2 t = new Test2();
  t.printClass(); 
}


class Test2{

 void printClass(){
  print(TestSketch.this.getClass());
 } 

}
```

Note that in the above example, the name of my sketch is TestSketch.

If it's in its own tab, then you need to pass an instance of the Processing sketch into the Game class via its constructor. Something like this:

From the main sketch tab:

```
void setup(){
  Test t = new Test(this);
  t.printClass(); 
}
```

And in its own tab called Test:

```
class Test{

  TestSketch testSketch;

  public Test(TestSketch testSketch){
    this.testSketch = testSketch;
  }

 void printClass(){
  print(testSketch.getClass());
 } 

}
```